# List printing same values as a buffer output instead printing unique values

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2

I have a list of features selected in the mapcanvas and for those selected features I am doing a buffer and printing the feature names that are inside the buffer. While printing, all values in the list have the same state and cities name. I don't know where I am wrong. I had also attached my code for reference.

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
selection = layer.selectedFeatures()
for feature in selection:
 buff = feature.geometry().buffer(80467.22489462817, 2)
 iterFeat = layer.getFeatures()
for f in iterFeat:
 geom2 = f.geometry()
 valTest = QgsGeometry.within(geom2, buff)
 if valTest:
    idx = layer.fieldNameIndex('name')
    idx1 = layer.fieldNameIndex('state')
    lsNearCities = []
    nearCity = feature.attributes()[idx]
    state = f.attributes()[idx1]
    state_and_cities = str(state) + "," + nearCity
    lsNearCities.append(state_and_cities)
    print lsNearCities
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want this line:

```
nearCity = feature.attributes()[idx]
```

to be:

```
nearCity = f.attributes()[idx]
```

Using the `feature` variable will always point to the last value in `selection`.

(This is untested advice, so I might not be understanding something fundamental here.)

Comment: Thank you Richard Morgan. Really great!That works.Its simple though.